# FPDF function control

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm new to programming and I'm creating a pdf with FPDF(A PHP Class). At the bottom of my code you will notice that I create a new page and call the function Header(). For some reason, the header is also applied to the first page. How do I only apply the header to the second page?

Here is a link to a live version of the pdf: http://fosterinnovationculture.com/experiments/fpdf/index-two.php

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

// classes
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Logo(){
        $this->Image('images/logo.png',1,5.5,3);
    }
    //change name of function
    function HeaderOne($xCor, $yCor, $text) 
    {
        $this->SetX($xCor);
        $this->SetY($yCor);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',18);
        $this->Cell(5,1,$text);
    }        
    //Add bottom border
    function BorderLine() 
    {
        $this->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
        $this->Rect(1, 10, 6.5, .015, 'F');        
    }
    function Footer()
    {
        // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-5.7);
        // Select Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Print centered page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'R');
    }
    function Header(){
        // Subtitle
        $this->SetY(.25);
        $this->SetX(1);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
        $this->Cell(6,1,'INNOVATION READINESS ASSESSMENT');
        // Line
        $this->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
        $this->Rect(1, .5, 6.5, .015, 'F');       
    }
}

//pdf document preferences
$pdf = new PDF('p', 'in', 'Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(1,1,1,1);

//Page 1
$pdf->SetDrawColor(238,170,40);
$pdf->SetFillColor(238,170,40);
$pdf->Rect(1, 1, 6.5, .25, 'F');
$pdf->Image('images/header.jpg',1,1.5,6.5,3.5,'JPG','');
$pdf->Logo();
$pdf->HeaderOne(1,9,'Innovation Readiness Assessment');
$pdf->BorderLine();

//Page 2        
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Header();

// Close and output file to the browser
$pdf->Output();
```

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the official documentation for [`Header()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/header.htm) and
[`AddPage()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm).

The `AddPage()` function already internally calls `Header()`. 
There is no need to call `Header()` explicitly here.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly did not even realize that FPDF already had a class called header. I though I was creating a new class. Thanks!